# A good data structure for storing and searching integers?

Tags: java, data-structures

Edit: Typos fixed and ambiguity tried to fix.

I have a list of five digit integers in a text file. The expected amount can only be as large as what a 5-digit integer can store. Regardless of how many there are, the FIRST line in this file tells me how many integers are present, so resizing will never be necessary. Example:

```
3
11111
22222
33333
```

There are 4 lines. The first says there are three 5-digit integers in the file. The next three lines hold these integers.

I want to read this file and store the integers (not the first line). I then want to be able to search this data structure A LOT, nothing else. All I want to do, is read the data, put it in the structure, and then be able to determine if there is a specific integer in there. Deletions will never occur. The only things done on this structure will be insertions and searching.

What would you suggest as an appropriate data structure? My initial thought was a binary tree of sorts; however, upon thinking, a HashTable may be the best implementation. Thoughts and help please?

Comment: `The expected amount could be in the millions` ... but the largest five digit number is 1 short of 100,000.  What is the nature of your search?

Comment: `Deletions will never occur. The only things done on this structure will be insertions and deletions. ` ... typo?

Comment: If there can be millions of integers all under 99999, then I would probably use a bucket of number counts. `numbers = new int[100000];` then get the occurrence of a number by indexing its bucket.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what operations you're performing? Is it purely insertions and deletions? Do you need to be able to iterate in sorted order? Search in a range? Merge things? Are duplicates allowed?

Comment: Deletions will never occur. The only things done on this structure will be insertions and deletions.  -> This is ambiguious. Please revise your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I have attempted to fix the typos and ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "search"? Do you just want to know if the data structure *contains* a certain value?

Comment: @Bohemian OP wrote that in the lastest edit.

Comment: *"upon thinking, a HashTable may be the best implementation"* -> `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the requirements you have are

- store a bunch of integers,
- where insertions are fast,
- where lookups are fast, and
- where absolutely nothing else matters.

If you are dealing with a "sufficiently small" range of integers - say, integers up to around 16,000,000 or so, you could just use a bitvector for this. You'd store one bit per number, all initially zero, and then set the bits to active whenever a number is entered. This has extremely fast lookups and extremely fast setting, but is very memory-intensive and infeasible if the integers can be totally arbitrary. This would probably be modeled with by `BitSet`.

If you are dealing with arbitrary integers, a hash table is probably the best option here. With a good hash function you'll get a great distribution across the table slots and very, very fast lookups. You'd want a `HashSet` for this.

If you absolutely must guarantee worst-case performance at all costs and you're dealing with arbitrary integers, use a balanced BST. The indirection costs in BSTs make them a bit slower than other data structures, but balanced BSTs can guarantee worst-case efficiency that hash tables can't. This would be represented by `TreeSet`.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much. I have to implement the data structures from scratch, I am not allowed to use Java.util or any other Java implementations. I was going to use the Hash Table, but I much prefer BST as I understand them better. I think explaining I can guarantee worst-case efficiency is also a good idea!

Thank you so much.

Comment: FYI, the first concept is implemented by `java.util.BitSet`.

Comment: @shmosel I had no idea that existed! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If the number of times each number occurs don't matter (as you said, only inserts and see if the number exists), then you'll only have a maximum of 100,000. Just create an array of booleans:

```
boolean numbers = new boolean[100000];
```

This should take only 100 kilobytes of memory.

Then instead of add a number, like 11111, 22222, 33333 do:

```
numbers[11111]=true;
numbers[22222]=true;
numbers[33333]=true;
```

To see if a number exists, just do:

```
int whichNumber = 11111;
numberExists = numbers[whichNumber];
```

There you are. Easy to read, easier to mantain.

Answer (score 0):

Given that

- All numbers are <= 99,999
- You only want to check for existence of a number

You can simply use some form of bitmap.

e.g. create a `byte[12500]` (it is 100,000 bits which means 100,000 booleans to store existence of 0-99,999 )

"Inserting" a number N means turning the N-th bit on.  Searching a number N means checking if N-th bit is on.

Pseduo code of the insertion logic is:

```
bitmap[number / 8] |= (1>> (number %8) );
```

searching looks like:

```
bitmap[number/8] & (1 >> (number %8) );
```

If you understand the rationale, then a even better news for you: In Java we already have `BitSet` which is doing what I was describing above.

So code looks like this:

```
BitSet bitset = new BitSet(12500);

// inserting number
bitset.set(number);

// search if number exists
bitset.get(number);  // true if exists
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` is the go-to data structure to "find", and here's a tiny amount of code you need to make it happen:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
Set<Integer> numbers = Stream.generate(scanner::nextInt)
    .limit(scanner.nextInt())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```